# How can I broadcast to multiple ssh using file descriptor?

Tags: ssh

I want to be able to broadcast the same commands to multiple servers interactively, meaning I want to send a command, view the result and send another command. The commands are arbitrary and cannot be scripted.

The question [How can I automate running commands remotely over SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243750/how-can-i-automate-running-commands-remotely-over-ssh) solves this problem very well if you're prone to using the tools suggested like: pssh, sdh, gsh, cluster-ssh.
But I am trying to find out if there a more low level solution, only by using the standard SSH.

My question is can you think of a way in BASH to open multiple SSHs, redirect into them a file, so everytime I write into the file, the new text is redirected into the SSH and executed.
If there is a reasoning behind why the above can't be done, I'd be happy to learn why is it not possible.

Comment: You might have better luck with this kind of question on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use **coprocesses**.

```
$ coproc foo { ssh -T foo.domain; }
```

Now `$foo` is an array of two file descriptors; `${foo[0]}` is ssh's stdout and writing to fd `${foo[1]}` will send to ssh's stdin.

```
$ echo "whoami" >&${foo[1]}
$ head -n 1 <&${foo[0]}
grawity
$
```

(Accessing `/proc/$$/fd/${foo[1]}` would work as well.)

---

Another way - **named pipes**.

```
$ mkfifo {foo,bar}.{in,out}
$ ssh foo <foo.in >foo.out &
$ ssh bar <bar.in >bar.out &
$ echo "whoami" | tee foo.in bar.in
```

Similar - **process substitution**.

```
$ echo "whoami" | tee >(ssh foo) >(ssh bar)
```

For more than one command:

```
$ mkfifo in
$ tee >(ssh foo) >(ssh bar) <in &
$ echo "whoami" >in
```

---

But since pipes break easily, you might have to resort to regular files.

(This example will put the file in `/dev/shm` to avoid hitting the disk every time.)

```
$ f=/dev/shm/in; touch $f
$ tail -f $f | ssh foo &
$ tail -f $f | ssh bar &
$ echo foo > $f 
$ echo bar >> $f; # note: >> for appending
```

And:

```
$ f=/dev/shm/in; touch $f
$ tail -f $f | tee >(ssh foo) >(ssh bar) &
$ echo foo >> $f
```

Comment: `>&${foo[1]}` won't work; there's no variable substitution in the file descriptor portion of redirections.  Your alternative using /proc/ would be necessary, since variables do work in filenames (even as part of redirections).  Additionally, `{in.out}` should be `{in,out}` (typo).

Comment: @Zenexer: I can assure you that `>&$var` works just fine in bash, and it seems to work even in ksh. (Otherwise they wouldn't have added `exec {var}<>…`, which kinda requires that to be useful.)

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to be working now.  I'm sure I was trying it with bash 4 before, so I'm not sure what the issue was.  I seem to recall it worked with exec but not other commands.